# Why use static enum?

Tags: java, static, enums

Sometimes I saw use static enum in android. but I can't find that information(I know enum in C) example,

```
   public static enum brush{
        static{
          array[0] = brush1;
          array[1] = brush2;
          array[2] = brush3;
          array[3] = brush4;
    }
}
```

but that is occurred error in project. error message is "Syntax error, insert "Identifier" to complete EnumConstantHeader" but I don't understand that's mean.

Comment: Learn more at the Oracle [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that this is an enum without a list of members. You'd normally have:

```
public enum Foo {
    VALUE1, VALUE2;
}
```

You *can* have an enum with no members, but you still need the semi-colon:

```
public enum Foo {
    ;
}
```

That's now valid, although not terribly useful.

The `static` part in the enum declaration is presumably because it's nested within another class. This isn't actually required - nested `enum` declarations are implicitly static.

The `static { ... }` is just a static initializer, run when the type is initialized.

Enums in Java are quite different from those in C. You should read [the `enum` section on the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an `}` from the `static` block declaration:

```
public static enum brush{
    static{
      array[0] = brush1;
      array[1] = brush2;
      array[2] = brush3;
      array[3] = brush4;
    }
}
```

There are several code smells here:

- The name `brush` does not adhere to naming conventions: it should be `Brush`
- `array` is not a meaningful name and I think it is also a reserved workd if I remember right. You should choose something which tells about its function
- `brush1` is not so meaningful either
- I can't see `array`'s declaration

What you are most likely try to achieve is something like this:

```
public static enum Brush{
    BRUSH_1, BRUSH_2, BRUSH_3, BRUSH_4;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A Java enum "is a type whose fields consist of a fixed set of constants ... you should use enum types any time you need to represent a fixed set of constants."

As specified in [Java Language Specification, Section 8.9:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

> Enum types must not be declared abstract; doing so will result in a
>   compile-time error. An enum type is implicitly final unless it
>   contains at least one enum constant that has a class body. It is a
>   compile-time error to explicitly declare an enum type to be final.
>   Nested enum types are implicitly static. It is permissible to
>   explicitly declare a nested enum type to be static. This implies that
>   it is impossible to define a local enum, or to define an enum in an
>   inner class. The direct superclass of an enum type named E is Enum.
>   An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum
>   constants. It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly
>   instantiate an enum type.

Because a Java enum type is good for defining a fixed set of constants, it's often used to represent constants like these in Java programs:

- *Days of the week*
- *Months in the year*
- *Cards in a deck*
- *Directions (north, south, east, west)*
- *Menu item options*
- *Defining arguments for a command-line program*
- *States in the United States (such as for a drop-down list)*

**Typical examples:**

**1)** *Declares the days of the week in an enum named Day.*

```
public enum Day
{
  SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

**2)**  *Declares the margin types that you can use when working with CSS:*

```
/**
  * Corresponds to CSS margins.
  */
public enum Margin
{
  TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, LEFT
}
```

So as you saw, it's worth nothing that because these are constants, we name them with all capital letters, which is consistent with Java naming conventions.

**Simple example -**

```
public class JavaEnumToStringExample
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // loop through the enum values, calling the
    // enum toString method for each enum constant
    for (Day d: Day.values())
    {
      System.out.println(d);
    }
  }
}

enum Day
{
  SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

**And the output -**

```
SUNDAY

MONDAY

TUESDAY

WEDNESDAY

THURSDAY

FRIDAY

SATURDAY
```

**Enum idioms-**

- Because they are constants, the names of an enum fields are created
  in uppercase (like other Java constants).
- You can use an enum any time you need to represent a fixed set of
  constants.

Comment: By the way, Java 8 and later now has built-in enums for [DayOfWeek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) and for [Month](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the correct implementation of  enum type in java. You should use enum types any time you need to represent a fixed set of constants.

syntax :

```
access-modifier enum enum-name
 {
     enum_type_1,
         enum_type_2      //(optioanl semi colon)
 }
```

Your `enum` more look like some *static method* again with some *static block* if we remove the `enum` keyword from it. Can't really understand the logic behind it. May be you are thinking to use the `enum` inside some class but nested enum declarations are implicitly static.