# When I have an enum defined in the same source file as the class that uses it, why is an import of the enum needed?

Tags: java, import, netbeans, enums

If a source file defining a class also defines an `enum` used by the class (and users of the class), why does the source file require an import of that `enum`? I am using Netbeans 8.2 by the way.

Here is a simple example:

```
// file and class name Foo, enum name Bar
package pak;

import pak.Foo.Bar; // <-- why is this required?

public class Foo {

    public static enum Bar { ZOT,BIF };

    public Foo() {}

    public void doFooBar(Bar op) { /* whatever */ }
}
```

Referring to the simple example above, the Netbeans compiler insists I include the import of the `enum`.

Why do I need to `import` when the `enum` is in the same source file as the class?

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me in NetBeans without using `import pak.Foo.Bar;`. Update your question with the following:[1] Your JDK version. [2] A  screenshot of your code (without the `import...`) after compilation in NetBeans, showing the error.

Comment: The question [Why do I need to import enum classes to use them when I already imported the package they're in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62783285/2985643) is qualitatively different to yours, but may still be of interest.

Comment: An `enum` in Java is implicitly `static`. No need for your use of `static`. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24383501/642706) and [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24383735/642706).